# Unable to rename Category column for Highcharts Pie chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts names the first column as `Category` by default. We can rename that using the xAxis title.

```
xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'custom column title'
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9cdj0rkg/

This works if the chart type is line but not with pie. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Take a look at the [demo example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/) from highcharts. Does this resolve your problem? There are no columns on a pie chart - what is your intended output?

Answer (score 0):

To change the values(not header) in the first exported CSV column, set `name` for points:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        y: 29.9,
        name: 'Jan'
    }, {
        y: 71.5,
        name: 'Feb'
    }, {
        y: 106.4,
        name: 'Mar'
    }, ...]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/26rc7nsa/

Comment: Adding names will change the value of the first column in each row. I'm after updating the first column header.

Comment: To change the column header use: `columnHeaderFormatter` funtion: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9hotb6wu/